# Swift detect properties of Other Audio with AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

AVAudioSession provides an isOtherAudioPlaying property to determine if another app is playing audio. Is there any way to determine  properties of this background audio signal (the audio data itself, volume levels, etc.) through this API or is this impossible in iOS? I am open to using other tools instead of AVAudioSession if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. You get no information about other processes' audio sessions. That would be a significant privacy concern. `isOtherAudioPlaying` is itself discouraged after iOS 8. (Apple recommends `secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` for the primary purpose of determining when to mute your own audio.)